# 12 ubuntu PCs in LAN : None getting connected via Samba

Tags: networking, samba

Well i know this is not a new question to this community but 
the problem is surely very new

I have got 12 pcs in our office which is ubuntu based. 
All of them are connected via lan wire or wifi. 
They all pass PING test 
The ip address is given to all the pcs by DCHP reservation from CISCO routers

We tried :- Samba, Changing the Interface File, everything ...but things are not working 
None of the pcs are getting connected to share files and folders.

Please give us exact way of how things can works

I have got samba installed on all pcs, user made, permission granted in config files. 
All done...

But still files are not getting shared.

A detailed help will very much be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In each of the 12 computers:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall samba samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient samba-vfs-modules samba-dsdb-modules libsmbclient python-samba samba-libs libwbclient0
smbpasswd -a user_pc01
smbpasswd -a user_pc02
smbpasswd -a user_pc03
smbpasswd -a user_pc04
smbpasswd -a user_pc05
smbpasswd -a user_pc06
smbpasswd -a user_pc07
smbpasswd -a user_pc08
smbpasswd -a user_pc09
smbpasswd -a user_pc10
smbpasswd -a user_pc11
smbpasswd -a user_pc12
mkdir /opt/folder_share
chmod -Rf 777 /opt/folder-share
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

In the open file, add this to the very end of the file:

```
[folder_share]
path = /opt/folder_share
available = yes
valid users = user_pc01, user_pc02, user_pc03, user_pc04, user_pc05, user_pc06, user_pc07, user_pc08, user_pc09, user_pc10, user_pc11, user_pc12
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Ctrl + O, save file. Ctrl + X, close nano.

The default user group of samba is: WORKGROUP

To access the network share use:

user_pcxx and password through the path smb://ip-pcxx/opt/folder_share

Comment: I did as you said, but did little differently.
I installed samba gui, from software centre , and shared the folder i wished. Then i went to config file and did all changes you said. 

Then i went to "connect to server" under networks and typed the path smb://192.168.112/home/folder_name
but then it pops up saying directory doesnt exist...what can be the problem